# rails render objects(hashes) in slim-lang

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, slim-lang

I try to render hash in my rails application to be considering as object in javascript.

```
div.sort-cartridges data-cartridges-selections=cartridges_selections
```

where `cartridges_selections` is function which return ruby hash.

But if in jQuery + coffee I try to fetch data object I get string:

```
$ ->
  console.log typeof $('.sort-cartridges').data('cartridges-selections')
  # => string
```

I tried to do JSON.parse, but it gave error to me. So, what I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct (find by myself):

```
= content_tag :div, id: 'sort-cartridges', data: { 'cartridges-selections' => cartridges_selections } do
  # my content
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this in view page.

```
div.sort-cartridges data: {cartridges-selections: cartridges_selections }
```

Comment: Have you tried above solution? your solution is also correct, you used rails, I have given slim syntax.